# CompletableFuture completion sequence in JAVA

Tags: java

I wrote a simple program

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
public class TestCompletableFuture {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<Void>()
            .whenComplete((res, exc) -> {
                System.out.println("inside handle.");
                if (exc != null) {
                    System.out.println("exception.");
                }
                System.out.println("completed.");
            }
        );

        future.completeExceptionally(new Exception("exception"));
        System.out.println("finished.");
    }
}
```

the output of the code:

```
finished.
```

When the main thread calls future, my understanding is. The method supplied into CompletableFuture should be called by completeExceptionally(). whenComplete().

Why isn't that the case?

Comment: Generally speaking, I think Java's completable future requires that you call `future.get()` before any future code is executed. (But I'm not an expert.) C.f. https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of you finishing the incorrect future. To see the `whenComplete` in action, you must obtain a reference to the first step and finish it:

```
public class TestCompletableFuture {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        /** get reference */
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        
        /** configure the action that to be run when the future is complete */
        CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = future
                .whenComplete((res, exc) -> {
                            System.out.println("inside handle.");
                            if (exc != null) {
                                System.out.println("exception.");
                            }
                            System.out.println("completed.");
                        }
                );

        future.completeExceptionally(new Exception("exception"));
        System.out.println("finished.");
    }
}
```

The code is now self-explanatory... Run the `(res, exc) ->` action when the `future` is finished. And simply use `completeExceptionally(...)` on the `future` to bring about that completion.

Also to be noted is the exceptional completion of all the aforementioned stages (futures) at this time:

```
System.out.println(future.isDone()); // true
System.out.println(future2.isDone()); // true

System.out.println(future.isCompletedExceptionally()); // true
System.out.println(future2.isCompletedExceptionally()); // true
```